# Handling dict type in dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have tab seperated data:

```
1   abc {'sci': 141, 'math': 274, 'eng': 218}
2   xyz {'sci': 151, 'math': 143, 'rock': 225}
3   pqr {'sci': 156, 'math': 151, 'rock': 84}
4   lmn {'sci': 91, 'math': 203, 'rock': 161}
```

schema is (id, user, mark_details)

I want to different columns created for every subject like below:

```
id, schema, sci, math, eng
1   abc 141 274 218
2   xyz 151 143 225
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you read the data from file? What does it look like?

Comment: I am reading it from .tsv file.